# How to check if both the EditTexts are empty or not?

Tags: java, android, null, android-edittext

How to check if both the EditTexts are empty ?
I tried a lot of things but nothing is working. I just want a toast saying "Data Incomplete" when either of the EditTexts are empty. I can do the toast part myself. Kindly help with the EditText part.

```
package com.maverick.mybmi;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final EditText entermass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entermass);
    final EditText enterheight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterheight);
    Button BMI = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BMI);
    BMI.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            double d = 0;
            double mass = Double.valueOf(entermass.getText().toString());           
            double height = Double.valueOf(enterheight.getText().toString());
            double heightF;
            heightF=height*0.3048;
            double bmi = mass/(heightF*heightF);
            d=bmi;
            int display = (int) bmi;

            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your BMI is " +display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
            toast.show();   
                if(d<15.0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Are Very Severely Underweight", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }   
                else if(d>=15.0 && d<=16.0){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Are Severely Underweight", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if(d>=15.0 && d<=16.0){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Are Severely Underweight", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else if(d>=16.0 && d<=18.5){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Are Severely Underweight", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else if(d>=18.5 && d<=25.0){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Are Normal (healthy weight)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else if(d>=25.0 && d<=30.0){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Are Overweight", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else if(d>=30.0 && d<=35.0){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Are Obese Class I (Moderately obese)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else if(d>=35.0 && d<=40.0){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Are Obese Class II (Severely obese)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            else if(d>40.0){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Are Obese Class III (Very severely obese)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }


    });

};};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the getText() method and then call toString() on it to get the Text.

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(entermass.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(enterheight.getText().toString())){
//enterheight or entermass is empty
}
```

Don't forget to check the [TextView API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) :-)

Answer (score 4):

you can use `TextUtils.isEmpty`. it checks both null values and empty string:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(entermass.getText().toString())) {
}
```

Comment: Should I put "if (TextUtils.isEmpty(entermass.getText().toString())) {
}" before the OnClickListener part ?

Comment: also inside onClick, just before trying to convert those to double, and if the check is true, simply return

Comment: @TheMaverick, It would be really great if you just accept then answer of any one.